# How to overcome Script Error in CHtmlView?

Tags: javascript, html, mfc, cview

I am using [CHtmlView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/42h6dke4.aspx) to show HTML pages from online into my application. Whenever the site/page tries to load any **'.js'** file or script it throws **Script Error** dialog and unable to load few items from the page. I have made `SetSilent(TRUE)` to avoid error messages, but still the Script Error occurs without showing the dialog. How can I overcome this problem?

Comment: This is not an answer, but I believe that the instance of IE embedded in the CHTMLView runs with increased security that may disable javascript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To avoid **JavaScript errors**, one must create a value in registry edit under the following registry path,

*32-bit :* `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\FeatureControl\FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION`

*64-bit :* `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\FeatureControl\FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION`

*value name :* `your application name(eg: sample.exe)`

*value :* [`refer to this page`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee330730%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#browser_emulation)

Comment: What was the solution? The MSDN web page might have changed and I don't know what value to use.

Comment: @Louis I guess you did not go through properly. The page clearly says what value should be used. Check out the "Browser Emulation" in the page.

Comment: I'm looking at the link, I don't see what value to use to stop the javascript errors either?

Comment: @HariDev If your application is x64 do you still need to use the Wow6432Node or is that only for x86 apps running on Windows x64 ?

Comment: @df234987 those are values that emulate the mentioned browser version on the HTML view on your application. If I still remember correctly, the application was targeted for x86. Currently, I'm not working on this.

Answer (score 0):

Editing the registry will suspend all alert messages. There is another way to avoid error alerts in your web page. Just add the following codes in the page:

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
    function fnOnError(msg,url,lineno){
        return true;
    }
    window.onerror = fnOnError;
</script>
```