# Does the Internet Explorer FeatureControl registry key still apply to Windows 10 and the CHtmlView?

Tags: windows, internet-explorer, mfc, com

I'm using MFC and CHtmlView. I came across articles like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22652097/how-to-overcome-script-error-in-chtmlview) that point to [Internet Feature Controls](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/general-info/ee330730(v=vs.85)?redirectedfrom=MSDN#browser_emulation).  I have a few questions hopefully someone knows the answer to:

1. Do those keys still apply to Win10?
2. On x64 Windows with a x64 app, do you still use the `Wow6432Node` version or is that only using an x86 app on x64?   I'm not sure if maybe the underlying HTML browser object is x86 so need to use `Wow6432Node` or it's related to the app?
3. Is there a best practice list of setting.  I noted that a lot of security restrictions are enabled for IE by default but not in apps using CHtmlView.

Comment: I'm guessing that those registry keys apply to Internet Explorer, not the OS.

Comment: Those keys still apply to IE browser in Windows 10. When add related registry key, we could select the DWORD (32-bit) value, you could check it by navigate to the related registry folder and check the existing items. [This article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/general-info/ee330733(v=vs.85)) provides an index to the registry keys associated with Internet feature controls, you could check it.

Comment: @ZhiLv-MSFT I guess the answer to #1 is yes, it still includes IE that is used by CHtmlView.  Answer to #3 is, no, you can look them up and apply as perhaps IE does.  But really the important one is #2.  Is the registry node to use based on the application (x64 vs x86) running on an x64 OS as normal or does one always use Wow6432Node on x64 Windows for both x64 and x86 applications?  I would presume as normal, but that linked article flat out said to use Wow6432Node on x64 windows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Do those keys still apply to Win10?

Yes, these registry keys still apply to IE browser in Windows 10.

> On x64 Windows with a x64 app, do you still use the Wow6432Node
>   version or is that only using an x86 app on x64? I'm not sure if maybe
>   the underlying HTML browser object is x86 so need to use Wow6432Node
>   or it's related to the app?

I have checked on my side (using Windows 64 bit and 32 bit OS), it is correct.

On Windows x64 OS, using the following registry path:

`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\FeatureControl\`

On 32 bit windows OS, using the following registry path:

`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\FeatureControl\`

> Is there a best practice list of setting. I noted that a lot of
>   security restrictions are enabled for IE by default but not in apps
>   using CHtmlView.

The [CHtmlView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/chtmlview-class?view=vs-2019) provides the functionality of the WebBrowser control within the context of MFC's document/view architecture. and the WebBrowser control is designed to work in full trust only. So when using them. it not have too much security restrictions, just according to the provided methods to use it.

Comment: So just to be clear, if using an x64 app on the x64 OS I still use Wow6432Node ?